# How to increase the limit of posting data from client to MVC Controller?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, postman

I'm posting some huge data from the client to the MVC controller. I got an error when my data is over 200,000(two hundred thousand) rows and approximately I consume 4 - 4.3 Mb. Is there any way to increase this limit? I get this error in both Postman and React.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly, for ASP.NET Core application, we can increase the default limit of 30MB by setting maxAllowedContentLength property in the web.config file. The default ASP.NET Core application template doesn’t create the web.config file. It is created when you publish the application. However, you can also add it manually (if not present) to the root of the application with the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
  For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <!-- This will handle requests up to 50MB -->
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is not totally true answer but I'll accept your answer. Because you gave me a view of where I should look to solve this problem. You forgot to add the  "<system.web><httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" /></system.web>"

My problem is about httpRuntime limit. But thanks to you I figured out where should I look into